# Databricks: cannot get personal access token. Error 400 Invalid resource ID

Tags: api, databricks

```
$ADB_WORKSPACE_ID = "5555555555555"
$ADB_WORKSPACE_URL = "adb-5555555555555.5.azuredatabricks.net"

$adbGlobalToken = (az account get-access-token --resource 2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d | ConvertFrom-Json).accessToken
$azureApiToken= (az account get-access-token --resource "https://management.core.windows.net/" | ConvertFrom-Json).accessToken

$headers = @{
    "Authorization" = "Bearer $adbGlobalToken";
    "X-Databricks-Azure-SP-Management-Token" = $azureApiToken;
    "X-Databricks-Azure-Workspace-Resource-Id" = $ADB_WORKSPACE_ID;
  
}

$body = @{
    "comment" = "This is an example token";
    "lifetime_seconds" = 300;
}

$uri = "https://${ADB_WORKSPACE_URL}/api/2.0/token/create"
write-host $uri

[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$json = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -ContentType "application/json" -Body $body  

write-host $json
```

Above code gives me the following error:

Invoke-RestMethod :
Error 400 Invalid resource ID.
HTTP ERROR 400
Problem accessing /api/2.0/token/create. Reason:
Invalid resource ID.

(FictiveDatabricks URL & ID )

Answer (score 0):

Like the error stated, I provided the wrong resource id.
The correct way to get it is the following:

```
$ADB_WORKSPACE_ID = "/subscriptions/$SubscriptionId/resourceGroups/$ResourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces/$WorkspaceName"
```

ResourceId is not the same as the WorkSpaceId.
ResourceId can also be found in the Databricks resource json in the "id" field.